# PyCharm Updating Python Interpreter Everytime Time I Run

Tags: python, pycharm, ide

**Background:**
I am very new to PyCharm and am currently trying to run a script, which works v. quickly and without issue on JupyterLab, but not so much in PyCharm; every time I run the script, I always see a very slow 'Background Task' that states `Updating Python interpreter - Updating skeleons... pandas.libs...` The script takes c.10mins to run vs. 5min in Jupyter Lab.

[image]
[image]

**Issue:**
I have not been able to triangulate why this script is taking so long to run and wanted some advice on basic troubleshooting.

**Useful information:**
My script is being run from a network drive and does read a `.ini` file, for the purpose of reading API details. The script uses the following dependencies/libraries -

```
from configparser import ConfigParser
import datetime as date
import datetime as dt
import datetime
from datetime import timedelta
from datetime import date
import itertools
import pandas as pd
from pandas import json_normalize
import requests as requests
from requests.auth import HTTPBasicAuth
import time
import json
import enlighten
import numpy as np
```

Furthermore, here is my config setup -

[image]

Does anyone have any suggestions on troubleshooting such an issue?

Comment: which version of pycharm and python you are using .   couple of issues are reported here , https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/PY-39067 , https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/PY-39583 . Try update to 2020.2.3

Comment: I'm using 2021.3.3 (Community Addition) And Py 3.9

Answer (score 2):

I worked out this is latency, caused by running from my network drive. Once I started creating and running similar scripts from my C: the issues disappeared.